# Spawn server cgi from html Javascript, at load time?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl

I have HTML and Javascript that passes Form Input variables to a server Perl cgi that works when Form Submit button is clicked (Post, Action, etc).  I write it, but not much experience in that environment.

Question is, I want the cgi to be spawned automatically (hopefully silently) when the HTML page is loaded. The Javascsript runs when loaded, but is there a way for it to then call the server cgi automatically (and pass the Form variables), without the form Submit button?   I fear Form requires Submit, but any exceptions? Or alternately, I know how to pass a parm string to the cgi, but I don't know how to spawn it automatically from Javascript? Typing http://...cgi spawns it, but automatically?

The cgi does have the option to "show no print" on screen, silently, in which case, can it run asynchronously, without needing a "return" back to restore the browser control? Cgi could return via a spawn of the referrer page (a second load)? But is that necessary?  As is, because of the printed screen from Submit, it does need a manual return.

Everything else is working, but both the automatic spawn and the silent return are a puzzle?  Ideas appreciated.

Comment: You can do this using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). If you use jQuery, you can [use the `$.ajax()` function](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/), which I find a lot less clunky than the pure JS approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to send a request to a server on page load.

You can do it pretty simple and straightforwardly via Javascript since submitting a form is not the only way to send a request. What you want is called `AJAX`.

If you use [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/), read about [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

If you don't use `jQuery`, there is still a way [to execute any Javascript on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) and [to send a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) (but you still better consider using `jQuery`).

Comment: Thanks much to both of you.  That is sounding right, and I think I have the idea now.  I'll dive into it.. Looks like a new world though... learning curve.  :)